# Xslt - for-each not producing the desired "attributes" inside an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Trying to get the attribute values inside an element, using for-each in xslt. 
Can some one help to get the desired output as, am getting only the name="id" and type="string" for the all the `<property name="id" type="string"/>`

Input Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:Example xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/internal">
        <inspection-result version="1">
            <form title="Form 1" history="true">
                <property name="id" type="string"/>
                <property name="name" type="string"/>
                <property name="default" type="string"/>
                <property name="time" type="string"/>
                <property name="status" type="string"/>
                <action name="click"/>
            </form>
            <next>Form2</next>
        </inspection-result>
    </ns2:Example>
```

Xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/internal"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
 <xsl:template match="inspection-result">
  <inspection-result>
   <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="//inspection-result/@version"/></xsl:attribute>
   <form>
    <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="//form/@title" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="history"><xsl:value-of select="//form/@history" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="//form/property">
     <property>
      <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="//form/property/@name" /></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="//form/property/@type" /></xsl:attribute>
     </property>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <action>
     <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="//action/@name" /></xsl:attribute>
    </action>
   </form>
   <next>
    <xsl:value-of select="//next" />
   </next>
  </inspection-result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<inspection-result version="1">
        <form title="Form 1" history="true">
            <property name="id" type="string"/>
            <property name="printerName" type="string"/>
            <property name="default" type="string"/>
            <property name="createdTimeStamp" type="string"/>
            <property name="status" type="string"/>
            <action name="click"/>
        </form>
        <next>Form2</next>
    </inspection-result>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already in the context of `form`, you need to use the *relative* path to its child elements, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@name" />
```

What you have now:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//form/property/@name" />
```

is an *absolute* path that selects **all** `@name` attributes in the entire document, starting from the root. And in XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns only the value of the first node in the selected node-set.

---

You overuse the `//` expression in other places, too. I would suggest you rewrite your template as:

```
<xsl:template match="inspection-result">
    <inspection-result>
        <xsl:attribute name="version">
            <xsl:value-of select="@version"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <form>
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="form/@title" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="history">
            <xsl:value-of select="form/@history" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="form/property">
            <property>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </property>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <action>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </action>
        </form>
            <next>
                <xsl:value-of select="next" />
            </next>
    </inspection-result>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot..couldn't reply at once, was wokring to get the flow for my service finished using this..still trying to learn xslt completely :)